пунктуация в предложении, содержащем вопрос
А я спросил, будешь ли ты делать ставки?

Повествовательное заканчивается точкой,
которая отменяется, если мы оформим предложение как прямую речь.
А я спросил: "Будешь ли ты делать ставки?"
Или:
"Ты что-то сказал? Я не расслышал, вода лилась". - "А я спросил, будешь ли ты делать ставки".

Возможны два варианта:
(1) А я спросил, будет ли он делать ставки.
Это косвенная речь: СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, вопросительная частица ЛИ в качестве союза.
В СПП вопросительный знак возможен только при сильно выраженной вопросительной интонации, здесь же скорее повествовательная интонация
(2) А я спросил: "Ты бУдешь делать ставки?"
Или:  А я спросил: "Будешь ли тЫ делать ставки?"
Это оформление прямой речи. Частица ЛИ в этом случае усиливает вопросительный характер дословного высказывания, причем ударением выделяется нужное слово.
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. В косвенной и прямой речи разные личные местоимения он и ты.
Розенталь § 2. Вопросительный знак
4. Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного 
предложения, если вопрос содержится и в главной, и в 
придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, 
либо в придаточной: Вы знаете, что такое сестры милосердия? 
(Остр.); Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от 
правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему 
дело? (Ч.)

Примечание. Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится: Я прервал речь Савельича вопросом, сколько у меня всего денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться (Н. О.).
Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л. Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М. Г.)
